# Get Discord bot to join when a user joins then leaves after a sound is played

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get the Discord bot to join when a specific user joins. The bot shows online in the Discord server, but it isn't joining when I join. Is there a way the username has to be formatted or am I missing something?

I thought it was the username missing the # tag for the username, but that didn't produce any results.

```
console.log('On');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates

  ]

});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  // Check if the user who joined is the specific user we want
  if (newState.member.id === 'SteveT') {
    // Check if the user joined a voice channel
    if (newState.channel) {
      // Play the specific sound
      newState.channel.join().then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\storr\Music\botsounds');
        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {

          // Leave the voice channel after the sound is played
          newState.channel.leave();
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

client.login('insertbotkey');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  // Check if the user who joined is the specific user we want
  if (newState.member.id === 'USE_YOUR_ID_PLS') {

    // Check if the user joined a voice channel
    if (newState.channel) {

      // Join the voice channel and play the specific sound
      newState.channel.join()
        .then(connection => {

          // Replace 'song.mp3' with the path to the audio file you want to play
          const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\storr\Music\botsounds\song.mp3');

          // Leave the voice channel after the sound is played
          dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            newState.channel.leave();
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
      }
  }
});
```

Do the same thing when you leave; just add an else. I was too lazy to write it again.

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly do I place the else in the code?

Comment: https://www.codebin.co/code/6ed7e13 here